# JavaScript close window when opener is closed in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

For my web application I need to close the child window whenever the parent window is closed. By "closed" I mean that the browser window is actually closed, not just navigated to a new page.

I have seen the "[How can I close the child window if the parent window is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013368/how-can-i-close-the-child-window-if-the-parent-window-is-closed)" question already, but mine is an extension on that. The answer to that question solves the problem of closing the child window on any unload event of the parent. However unload != close (IMO); just clicking on a link triggers the unload event.

Since there isn't an "onclose" event in JS, I decided that the best method is on the parent's unload event setTimeout on the child to see if it's parent still exists and close if not:

```
var w = window.open("", "Logger", "height=480,width=640,resizeable,scrollbars=yes");
if (w) {
  JSEvents.on(window,'unload',function(){
    if (w && !w.closed) {
      w.setTimeout(function(){
        //IE this==w.opener
        if (!w.opener || w.opener.closed) {
          w.close();
        }
      },500);
    }
  });
}
```

However, I believe that I have pretty conclusively shown that in IE(7) you cannot use setTimeout during the unload event on either the parent or child window. In the above example `this == w.opener` inside of the setTimeout anonymous function. This test never produces an alert:

```
JSEvents.on(window, 'unload', function(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){alert('HERE');},500);
});
```

A straight `alert` without the `setTimeout` will produce the alert.

Is there a trick to setting a setTimeout on the child from the parent that I can use?

Is there another method for detecting when the parent is closed that I can use?

It is much easier to do in FF, so I am focusing on getting this to work under IE.

Comment: I have discovered that in IE the `document.activeElement.toString()` is a URL if the page is transitioning, but `[object]` if closing. Combining this with my setTimeout method above I believe I can achieve my goal.  If this works out I will post my solution below. But it will require extensive testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the correct way to add a script into the child window's scope is to use the DOM to create the script tag.  The following code works to check if the parent window is open still a quarter second after it unloads in IE.

```
var w = window.open("", "Logger", "height=480,width=640,resizeable,scrollbars=yes");
if (w) {
  JSEvents.on(window,'unload',function(){
    if (w && !w.closed) {
      var srpt = w.document.createElement('script');
      srpt.type = 'text/javascript';
      srpt.text = 'window.setTimeout(function(){if(!window.opener||window.opener.closed){window.close();}},250);';
      w.document.body.appendChild(srpt);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help in pointing me in this direction. The solution was just figuring out how to dynamically insert a new script tag with text content instead of a `src`.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a trick to setting a setTimeout on the child from the parent that I can use?

You can't do it with code from the parent in IE. When IE closes a window, the members you defined from code inside it are gone, and references to those members (such as the child's timeout pointing to your function) are left dangling. Depending on what version of IE you've got, maybe nothing will happen, or maybe you'll get a “can't execute code from a freed script” error.

You *can* do it inside the child. The parent could set a flag on the child onunload (eg. w.parentUnloaded= true) which a setInterval poller on the child could check for, and close itself —

```
if (window.parentUnloaded && (!window.opener || window.opener.closed))
```

Is this an IE bug? Well... other browsers react differently to unloaded scripts, certainly. But there is no standard that says what is supposed to happen here. Even within the same browser series, behaviours change as browsers are updated to avoid cross-context scripting issues.

With stuff like this and event timing issues(*), cross-window scripting is much more difficult to get right than it looks. It's generally best avoided; if you can put your ‘pop-ups’ in divs in the main page, it is usually better to do that.

(*: there are cases(**) where an event can be fired in one window and execute whilst JavaScript in another window is still in the process of running. So window ‘a’ could call a method on window ‘b’ and have that execute whilst other code in window ‘b’ is still in progress. This can dramatically confuse the scripts in window ‘b’, if they are written under the normal JavaScript assumption that there is only one thread of execution active at once. This is why I suggest using the poller in the child rather than having the parent explicitly call the child. In the future we will use HTML5's postMessage method to avoid these problems.)

(**: You could very well argue that this should never happen, and it certainly is weird, but it does happen in many browsers, in particular when modal dialogues are involved or some versions of the IE Sun Java plugin are in use.)

> You can't just leave pop-up windows lying around after the application is closed; it's just not polite.

Some would say the impoliteness was opening the pop-ups in the first place. ;-)

It would seem to me that it would make sense to close any child windows when the parent is left, regardless of whether the user was closing the window, or just navigating back to his home page, or a bookmark, or typing an address, or something. Personally I'd probably want to lose the child windows on a refresh too, if I'm trying to ‘reset’ the application to a beginning state.

If you have multiple documents the parent is going to be navigating between which are all part of the same application and should not close the children, you're making things really hard for yourself! :-) However you could adapt the above ‘child window if’ approach to try to sniff the opener.location and see if that's within your application to decide whether to close or not. The trick is if the opener had been navigated to a different domain, the access would throw a security exception, so you'd have to wrap the location access up in a try...catch block that also closed the windows if the opener location was unreadable.

bucabay wrote (and Anthony something similar):

> The browser considers the window closed once you refresh or close the window. So as far as the child is concerned, it's opener is gone once you refresh the parent.

That's very sensible and logical. Browsers probably *should* have one ‘window’ per document like that. But try it — they don't. A child pop-up retains access to its opener (and, as long as that opener is a document in the same security context, the contents of the opener), over a refresh of the opener, in IE/FF/Op/Saf/Chr.

Comment: This is very helpful breakdown of my issue, thank you. Unfortunately my web application is something that web developers use on their site. The tool can only insert things into existing pages, not create new pages. This is why my pop-up (which is a log for the developer of events/actions they made while using the app) uses a blank page. By keeping the window open between page transitions that historic log is maintained for their work session. The tricky bit is that if they close the parent window, but leave the child around the log isn't reset and becomes confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In pop up window: (this works if the opener is closed OR changes domains)

```
 var int = window.setInterval(function(){
   // On opener domain change, all browsers throw an error. Lets use that error to our advantage using try/catch:
   try
     {
    if(opener && typeof opener.document != 'undefined')
    {     
     // Adding this variable fixes IE8. Why? Because F U thats why.
     var openerRef = window.opener.location.host;
    }
    else{
     // Loads the survey when opener is closed
     window.location = 'exit-survey.jsp';
    }
     }
   // Loads the survey if an error throws (error throws when opener changes domain)
   catch(err)
     {
    window.location = 'exit-survey.jsp';
     }
  }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the function inside the opened window like this:

```
window.closeWithParent = function() {
  if (!window.opener || window.opener.closed) {
    window.close();
  }
};
window.parentClosing = function() {
  window.setTimeout(window.closeWithParent, 500);
};
```

Then from your parent window:

```
JSEvents.on(window,'unload', function() { 
  if (w.parentClosing) w.parentClosing(); 
});
```

I'm not sure, but I think that interfacing with the window object across windows might be causing the problem you are seeing.  Also, this way the setTimeout is called in the child windows scope (hopefully) instead of your parent window, which is being unloaded (this losing any timeouts).

Comment: Actually within the `w.setTimeout` function `this=w.opener` so I think that the scope is actually the parent window, not the child's.

The child window is actually a blank window that I am writing too entirely via JS. There is no default content, and I cannot seem to add a <script> tag to the page. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Hrm... I would think it would be easier to have it open a "static page" on the server that loads JS/CSS content, the `<body>` could still be blank, but then you have a window, that exists in the same domain as well (less security issues)

Comment: Unfortunately the nature of my application is that I can only insert a script tag into existing HTML, I cannot serve any new pages on the domain. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the browsers perspective a window is a concept which is created to display the content of a document.  When you navigate from that document to another that window is closed and a new one is created.

The fact that the browsers conceptual windows are hosted by an actual client window owned by the browser and that client window may be re-used to display subsequent documents isn't actually any of your business (if you don't mind the phrase).

Its how the browser chooses to display the content, that window having a close button that may be potentially clicked by the user is outside of what most browsers consider that any host document needs to know.

Hence any trick you might invent to circumvent this now, if it works at all, may be closed by tighter security in later versions of a browser.

My advice would be to drop this requirement.

Comment: spot on. But you can still check if windows are open for a particular domain indirectly.

Comment: If you want to write a user friendly web application it is the application's business. You can't just leave pop-up windows lying around after the application is closed; it's just not polite.

Comment: @Rob: I understand that you want to provide the best experience you can to the user, however, the browser is first and foremost designed to give client who owns the browser access to public web sites.  The security risks this exposes the user to requires the significant effort be put into sandboxing this activity.  This requirement is often at odds with creating complete apps that work the way other clients with full access to the host would be able to deliver.

Comment: @AnthoneyWJones What security issues are those? Every browser out there specifically allows a window opened with JS to be closed by JS from the parent or child. The issue here is with my specific use case, the popup window doesn't have a URL.

Comment: Since the window doesn't have a URL IE will consider it to be in a different domain to the window that opens it.  Ordinarily open will return null in this case or at least you will get permission errors when attempting to manipulate the window.

Comment: Not true, IE considers it the same domain without a URL.

Answer (score 1):

The browser considers the window closed once you refresh or close the window. So as far as the child is concerned, it's opener is gone once you refresh the parent.

So you cannot test if a window just refreshed, or opened another instance on that same domain using JavaScript references. (such as window.opener)

You can however create indirect references to other windows and save them in any browser storage that is cross window, or even server storage. Having the storage reflect the state of the window will allow other windows to observe that window even though they do not have a reference.

You could use cookies, or [DOM Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_storage) etc. I have a library that uses cookies (it was written a year ago when DOM storage was not supported - FF2+, IE8+ I think). If you want to see it as an example, I can do that.

Anyway, what you can do is keep a piece of data that represents the parent window. Keep it updated at regular intervals, and poll it from the child.

Example with cookies:

```
// parent
setInterval(function() { setCookie('parent_alive', new Date()) }, 1000);
// child
setInterval(function() { if (readCookie('parent_alive') < new Date()-5000) window.close() }, 1000)
```

Here the child will close 5 seconds after the parent does not update the cookie "parent_alive". The main problem is that internet connection may prevent a page from loading for 5 seconds, by which the child thinks it was closed. So it is a balancing act.

Note the polling is quite efficient if you use session cookies since they stay in memory. However, if you use persistent cookies you will probably be hitting the disk which would suck.